# How to get the values from the base class in c# without using property name

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have a method which calls the sqlquery method of my dbcontext methods are below:

```
private IEnumerable<object> getRawDataDb(DependencySheet sheet, string name)
{
    switch(name)
    {
        case "DefaultData":
              return sqlQuery.Database.SqlQuery<DefaultData>(sheet.Query);

        case "OpenInventory":
               return sqlQuery.Database.SqlQuery<OpenInventory>(sheet.Query);

        case "CompQuals":
               return sqlQuery.Database.SqlQuery<CompQual>(sheet.Query);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Calling the above method from below

```
var rawData = getRawDataDb(dependentData, sheetName).ToList();
```

and then iterating it with foreach loop as below:

```
foreach(var raw in rawData)
{
    var tw = raw.GetType().BaseType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance); 
}
```

Now while executing when I want to get the values shown below into the image which is getting in the raw object :

[image]

but I am not able to get the values and I have used gettype already.

thanks
daman

Comment: Why not just have three methods that return values of the correct type, and avoid this needless `name` parameter and the `switch`. It seems like you're creating a problem by shoving this all into a single swiss-army-knife method.

Comment: Actually we are trying to make it a generic method

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you have BaseClass:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And some inherited from it (for example OpenInventory):

```
public class OpenInventory : BaseClass
{
    public string AnotherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can write:

```
public IEnumerable<BaseClass> getRawDataDb(DependencySheet sheet, string name)
{
    //type declaration OpenInventory must be located at the same assembly with getRawDataDb
    var type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(x => x.Name == name).First();

    var res = new List<BaseClass>();
    var source = sqlQuery.Database.SqlQuery(type, sheet.Query);

    foreach (var item in source)
        res.Add(item as BaseClass);

    return res;
}
```

And it will executed as you wanted:

```
var res = getRawDataDb(dependentData, sheetName).ToList();
```

As a result you will be able to call BaseClass's properties explicitly:

```
res.First().ID
```

And you also can call another properties via explicit conversion:

```
(res.First() as OpenInventory).AnotherProperty;
```

Comment: Can you describe what is wrong with "T" in detail? I tried this code on my own and all is works.

Comment: its working now but I want that getRawDataDb<OpenInventory>(dependentData).ToList(); "OpenInventory" should also be dynamic or I can call all the classes mentioned in EF

Comment: I changed my answer is it what you wanted?